# Using WP_Query to Retrieve ACF Field Value

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Can someone please share PHP code to retrieve an ACF field value using WP_Query? The following retrieves the field value, but I would like to accomplish this using WP_Query instead so that it can be used as a Meta Query:

`<?php $field = get_field_object('field_64fa6f6063934'); ?> <?php echo $field['value']; ?>`

I've also tried

`<?php $field = get_field_object('field_64fd4d406393c'); echo $field['value']; ?>`

Thank you

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you google `acf meta query` and find their excellent explanation? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Comment: I did, however, the page doesn't provide an example on how to retrieve the field value using wp_query. It provides example on querying posts with the field value (meta value) defined.

Comment: From the site: `Please note these examples use the WP_Query object [...]`. If you want to retrieve an ACF field value by something different than the meta_key, you should probably update your question.

Comment: Please tell me where the page provides an example of retrieving the field value using WP_Query?

Comment: What do you mean by `retrieving`? `WP_Query` holds a collection of `posts` that match certain criteria and the meta query is used to associate these criteria to `meta_key` and/or `meta_value`. When iterating through the resultset, you can use WordPress' functions to retrieve the values with `the_field('key')` or `get_field('key')` just like you do with `the_title()` or `get_the_title()` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve an ACF field value using WP_Query, you can use the `meta_query` parameter in the `WP_Query` function. Here's an example code snippet that retrieves the value of an ACF field with the field key `field_64fa6f6063934`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_64fa6f6063934',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $field_value = get_field( 'field_64fa6f6063934' );
        // Do something with the field value
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

In this example, we're querying for posts of type `post` that have a value for the ACF field with the key `field_64fa6f6063934`. The `compare` parameter is set to `EXISTS` to ensure that we only retrieve posts that have a value for this field.

Inside the loop, we're using the `get_field()` function to retrieve the value of the field for the current post. You can replace `field_64fa6f6063934` with the key of the ACF field you want to retrieve.

Note that you need to call `wp_reset_postdata()` after the loop to restore the global post data to its original state.